# Raster error 'TypeError: Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' when creating Arcmap script

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, arcgis-10.7

I am writing an Arcpy script to use in ArcMap (ArcGIS 10.7.1) as a tool to interpolate existing soil points, and make a nutrient recommendation afterwards. However, I'm getting the `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` error, and I'm not sure what's going on. The funny thing is that this script will run as  a standalone script, but when I upload it into Arcmap to be used as a tool, it gives me this error. How can I fix the problem?

The code I have is shown below. I have commented out the Arcmap parameter type that I set each parameter as when I upload the script as a tool.

```
#Importing required modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy.da import *

#Environment settings
env.workspace = #Workspace parameter
env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set main field parameters
fieldBoundary = #Feature class
soilPoints = #Feature class (points to be interpolated)

crop = #String, indicating crop type
yieldGoal = #Long integer, such as 200
nField = #Field (of the soilPoints) indicating nitrogen levels at each point
organicMatter = #Field (of the soilPoints) indicating organic matter at each point
previousCrop = #String indicating previous crop grown

#Check out extensions
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
arcpy.CheckkOutExtensison("3d")

#Interpolate nitrogen soil points
field = nField
n_krig = Kriging(soilPoints, field, kModelOrdinary, cellSize, kRadius, outRaster)
nitrogenField = ExtractByMask(n_krig, fieldBoundary)

#Interpolate organic matter soil points
field = organicMatter
om_krig = Kriging(soilPoints, field, kModelOrdinary, cellSize, kRadius, outRaster)
organicMatterField = ExtractByMask(om_krig, fieldBoundary)

#Set previous crop adjustments, which will be based off of user selection in parameters
if previousCrop == "Corn":
           pca = int(0)
        elif previousCrop == "Wheat":
            pca = int(0)
        elif previousCrop == "Milo":
            pca = int(0)
        elif previousCrop == "Sunflowers":
            pca = int(0)
        elif previousCrop == "Soybeans":
            pca = int(40)
        elif previousCrop == "Alfalfa: >5 plants/square foot":
            pca = int(120)
        elif previousCrop == "Alfalfa: 2-5 plants/square foot":
            pca = int(80)
        elif previousCrop == "Alfalf: 2-3 plants/square foot":
            pca = int(40)
        elif previousCrop == "Alfalfa: <2 plants/square foot":
            pca = int(0)
        else:
            pca = int(0)

#Nitrogen needs equation. Produces a raster output
#ERROR OCCURS AFTER THIS LINE

nitrogen_recommendation = ((1.6 * yieldGoal) - (organicMatterField * 20) - (nitrogenField) - (pca))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\script.py", line 125, in <module>
    nitrogen_recommendation = ((1.6 * yieldGoal) - (organicMatterField * 20) - (nitrogenField) - (pca))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: @user2856 no it does not. After adjusting that code, I get this new error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\script.py", line 125, in <module>
    nitrogen_recommendation = ((1.6 * int(yieldGoal)) - (Raster(organicMatterField) * 20) - (Raster(nitrogenField)) - (pca))
TypeError: expected a raster or layer name
```

Comment: try yieldgoal =  int('{0}'.format(200)). Do you use GetParameterAsText when use it as a tool in Arcmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the standalone script is dynamically typed and anticipates the type of the variables, ArcMap is a little more sensitive to variable types. So, the following works:

`nitrogen_recommendation = (1.6 * float(yieldGoal)) - (organicMatterField * 20.0) - (nitrogenField) - float(pca)`